# Logging network traffic

Tags: networking, windows

Don't know if this is right forum, so please excuse me for that.

I have created a web service in ColdFusion and other application from outside the network is trying to access it via SOAP request which results in failure. I have logging enabled in my web service code which works fine when I'm testing on my end.

Is there a way to log network traffic to reproduce\capture this error on your system.  Fiddler & Wireshark would capture traffic to the browser, but we need to capture server to server communications.

Comment: Wireshark can capture all network traffic, including server to server.

Comment: But how do I do it with it's help. I don't know when 3rd party is going to hit my service and I want to log the error they're getting which is happening before it is even hitting the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabled server log and went through it. Eventually ended up changing datatype of passed parameters to string and converting to my end.

Answer (score 3):

If the server is running Linux, keep tcpdump running and logging everything, and look at them later.

Assuming your service is listening to port *80* on *eth0*:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 tcp port 80 -W 10 -C 20 -w service_dump
```

This will create a series of 10 *service_dump* files on current directory, rotating every file as they reach 10MB.

You can later run *tcpdump -r* on the files to look for your error messages, or load the files on wireshark.

Comment: I'm on Windows Server 2008 with IIS Web server.

Comment: If there's a Linux box on the network, you can configure Windows to use the Linux box as the gateway, and do the same.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a better question for Server Fault or Stack Exchange, but are they getting a failure to connect error? What type of error are they getting?

If they are receiving a failure to connect, logging just at the server doesn't solve much if the traffic is not being routed to the server.

- Is your application accessible through the internet?
- Is your application behind a firewall?
- Does your application force the use of HTTPS?

Comment: They are getting `500 - Internal server error`. However webservice can be accessed from anywhere and they are able to see wsdl too

Comment: If you are allowed to, install Wireshark on your server. Log all data on your active interface (Typically one of the Local Area Connections). Try this for capturinf SOAP messages https://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-users/201009/msg00106.html